# Can I make bone broth with bones without marrow?

Tags: stock, bones

I bought some marrow bones from the butcher, roasted them, ate the delicious marrow.  I then decided to make broth out of it.  I've made broth many times with chicken carcasses, but not beef bones from which I have already eaten the marrow out of.  Anyone have experience making broth from beef bones without the marrow?

Comment: I do not agree with the pedantic editing of this question.  It conveys no information more clearly now than it did previously.

Comment: Please read the corresponding Meta post [here](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3329/why-are-people-here-messing-with-my-posts).

Comment: Hi Mega Man and welcome! I agree with you about the editing. Editing is meant to make improvements or clarify a question. In this case, however, I don't feel that the edit made any significant improvement to your question, nor do I see any problem with it as you wrote it. Therefore, I rolled it back to your original post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're proposing is similar to 'remouillage' ('rewetting'; sometimes called 'second stock').  It's a stock made from bones that have already been used to make stock.

It may not be quite as flavorful as you'd get from your first stock, but in your case, you haven't made stock with it, so any water-soluble bits that haven't been removed would still be on/in the bones.  And if the bones were roasted, they'll have extra flavor from the browning of the bits of flesh that can remain on the bones.

You'll also still get flavors from any vegetables you might use, so you can make a beef/vegetable stock.  Bonus points if they're also things that might have been trash -- parsley stems, the ends of onions, that sad looking pepper that you found in the back of your fridge, etc.  Growing up, my mom would keep a bag in the freezer of such things, and when she had a carcass, she'd toss it all in the pot and let simmer.**

This second stock can then be used in case where you might not want the full strength stock, but as you found, you can also reduce it to intensify the flavors (but if you do that, go light on the salt)

** She'd also make seafood stock from crab shells (including legs), or shrimp shells, tails and heads; her mother grew up in the Great Depression, and you learn to be frugal.

Comment: And if you want more examples of this frugal style, check out [Great Depression Cooking](http://greatdepressioncooking.com/Depression_Cooking/Welcome.html) and the [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/DepressionCooking).  (no relationship, other than a fan who has the DVDs)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you won't have much flavor in a stock made from bones with no marrow.

Stock gets that delicious flavor not really from *bones*, but from the marrow and connective tissue on/inside the bones.  Most beef marrow bones don't have a great deal of connective tissue on them, and you've already eaten the marrow, so there's just not much left to flavor a stock.

Comment: You *might* get something closer to remouillage, a 'rewetting' of the bones.  (ie, making a second thin stock from the bones that had already been used for stock making).

Comment: @Joe  Huh.  I'd never heard of that... I'd always heard that once you made stock from your bones, there *shouldn't* be anything left to extract a second time.

Comment: @Joe i boiled the bones afternight (thanks for the term remouillage, that's a new one for me!), and then reduced ~3 lbs of marrowless bones, various spices to ~12 oz of glace and pleased to see that it gelled up nicely after reducing and refrigeration.

Comment: @Joe Since OP found your comment more helpful than my answer, perhaps you should post it as an answer so it can be accepted?

Comment: @senschen I started last night, then I fell asleep.